# Slide-in from the left with width: auto

Tags: css

I'm implementing a toolbar using flex boxes and want optional sections to appear by smoothly sliding in from the left.

At the start, the bar should look as if the new element didn't exist, and at the end as if the animation never took place

Animating `0% { margin-left: -<width> }` works exactly as intended, but only when the element's width is known at that point; I need it to work with `width: auto` (i.e. unset width) or other non-lengths like when flexing.

```css
@keyframes appear {
  0% { margin-left: -30ch; }
}
div.a {
  width: 30ch; /* << should work without that */
  flex: none; /* << stretch: should work with flex */
  animation: appear 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.root {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.a, .b, .c {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
}
.b { flex: 2 }
.a { background: #88f }
.b { background: #8d8 }
.c { background: #f88 }
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="a">Some new stuff</div>
  <div class="b">Hello</div>
  <div class="c">World</div>
</div>

<div class="root">
  <div class="a">Some longer content sliding in</div>
  <div class="b">Hello</div>
  <div class="c">World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Width:auto;` is not animatable. Use `max-width:1000px;` or something larger than the width will ever need to be. So the code would be:

```
 width:auto;
 max-width:1000px;
```

Comment: the animation experience will be hardly adjustable on such extreme widths - cause you'll see animating only the portion from>to that 1000px (which can be i.e: (the last) 100px (of 1000) Hope you get the point)

Comment: Animating the width creates a "roll out" effect, not the "slide out" that animating margin-left does. (I've actually fallen back to that for now, it's okay when using linear interpolation; and `max-width: 100%` works too, but I'd like the slide effect from the snippet)